# Условие в определении элемента массива

Tags: php, yii

Хочу сделать такую проверку

```
'visible'=> '($data->type == 3)? true: false',
```

а не получается.

```
$myarray[] = array(
    'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn', //кнопка добавления данных 
    'template' => '{add}',
    'visible'=> '($data->type == 3)? true: false',
```

**Обновление**

Может проблема в том, что это кнопки? Он либо все скрывает, либо все показывает. Сделал такой финт

```
$myarray[] = array(    
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn', //кнопка 
    'template' => '{add}',
    //'visible'=> $data->type == 3,       
    'buttons' => array(
        'add' => array(//the name {reply} must be same
            'label' => '+', // text label of the button
            'url' => '$data->id."|".$data->name."|".$data->type',               
            'click' => 'function(){
                        data=$(this).attr("href").split("|")
                                if (data[2] == 3){
                        $("#myModalHeader").html(data[1]);
                        $("#myModalBody").load("' . $this->createUrl('analizCreate/modalcreate') . '/?id="+data[0]+"");
                        $("#myModal").modal();}
                        return false;
                    }',
            ////Your URL According to your wish
            'options' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-small btn-success' ,
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кавычки - это не обязательный элемент синтаксиса массивов, как полагают многие начинающие пользователи РНР, а всего лишь а ограничитель строк.
В данном случае никакой строки в массив мы не пишем, и поэтому кавычки не нужны.
Как и тернарный оператор, поскольку оператор сравнения уже возвращает нужное значение.

Поэтому

```
'visible' => $data->type == 3,
```

[прекрасно работает](http://3v4l.org/baiO8)

Comment: к сожалению не работает тоже

Comment: может там действительно не тройка приходит? как мне сдапмить тогда значение? хотя 'url' => '$data->id."|".$data->name."|".$data->type', корректно мне тройку отрисовываеет